# Using Xpath to select blockquote text including <br/>

Tags: iphone, parsing, xpath

So, I have HTML like this:

```
<blockquote>TEXT<br/>MORE TEXT<br/>SOME MORE TEXT</blockquote>
```

Basically, I need to get all of the text inbetween the blockquote tags, including the new-lines.
Using "//blockquote" only returns the last line (SOME MORE TEXT) and using "//blockquote/text()" returns every line as a seperate item in the array.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath:

```
//blockquote
```

will return all blockquote elements no matter where they are.

XPath:

```
//blockquote/text()
```

will return the child text nodes of all blockquote elements

XPath:

```
//blockquote//node()
```

will return any descendant node (text or tags) of all blockquote elements, that is, in your case:

```
TEXT<br/>MORE TEXT<br/>SOME MORE TEXT
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now it just includes <br/> in the array as "(null)". The strings are still seperate, now with just a "(null)" item inbetween.

Comment: My answer is related to pure XPath usage. Use that with any XPath 1.0 compliant tester and you will see that it is correct. My answer does not address any TFHpple XPath related issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry, using [element content] returns (null). [element name] returns br. I guess I'll have to check through the array for elements named br then combine the two strings before and after...

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is behaving properly. br is interpreted as another tag by the parser.

You will have to modify your code like this (I havent compiled this source code):

In your  `- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName`

Create a NSMutableString *finalValue;

```
if([elementName isEqualtoString"@"br"])
{
finalValue = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@\n",finalValue];
}
```

So basically you will have to append a \n to the parsed value when you encounter a br tag end.

Comment: I'm not actually using NSXMLParser, I'm using the TFHpple class. Would NSXMLParser be a better idea? The code for Xpath in TFHpple is NSArray *array = [xpathParser search:@"//blockquote/text()"];.